# Assigning multiple values to a key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that needs its values to be 2D lists. I am having trouble adding these second values to a key. I have two lists, the first a list of values then a list of keys that is composed of additional lists.

So far I have this code:

```
 for i in range(len(keyList)):
      if keyList[i] in theInventory:
           value = theInventory[keyList[i]]
           value.append(valueList[i])
           theInventory[keyList[i]] = value
      else:
           theInventory[keyList[i]] = valueList[i]
```

The problem is that the output has a list of entries for the first added to the list then it has the lists I am looking to add to my dictionary.

Like so:

```
 [value, value, value, [list], [list]]
```

How do I make the first entry be entered into the dictionary as its own list?

Comment: Ugh of course it was that easy! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use extra `[]` around `valueList[i]`:

```
theInventory[keyList[i]] = [valueList[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code as follows.  The `append()` method mutates the list, so there is no need to assign the result of the append back the `theInventory`.  Further there is no need to use `value` at all, instead you can just directly append to the item in the dictionary.

```
for i in range(len(keyList)):
      if keyList[i] in theInventory:
           theInventory[keyList[i]].append(valueList[i])
      else:
           theInventory[keyList[i]] = [valueList[i]]
```